# Configuring Vim for C++

Tags: c++, vim, configuration

I would like to make vim my C++ editor. I have very little experience working with it 
and need help in configuring vim to work with C++.
I need such features as

- code-complete (for stl and for my classes)
- switching between .cc and .h files
- may be some more tricks you, C++ and vim gurus, have.

May be you could provide some configs (with explanations), or links to tutorials, plugins I could make use of?

Comment: +1 for the sheer masochism of wanting to use vim as your IDE :) vim has its uses (especially for editing files remotely in my experience), but anyone who actually *wants* to use it for code editing has chutzpah in my view.

Comment: @sgolodetz: Then there are quite a lot of people with chutzpah out there.

Comment: @Jefromi: Yup I do realise that :) It has always seemed like masochism to me though...in a sort of slightly admirable way.

Comment: @wilhelmtell: I guess you could read it that way if you wanted -- actually I was just bored whilst doing some work on my doctorate and saw a post I felt like commenting on. Not really interested in starting a big debate on the merits of vim or otherwise, just stating a point of view. Personally I find vim helpful when editing the odd text file using Putty, but using it as my IDE doesn't seem in any way appealing. At the same time, I have a certain amount of respect for anyone who does use it for that -- they obviously have a higher pain threshold than I do.

Comment: In retrospect, I guess posting the equivalent of "I'm a bit dubious about vim" on a post likely to be frequented by a lot of vim enthusiasts might have been a little provocative -- it was meant to be a tongue-in-cheek comment rather than the start of an argument though.

Comment: I did give [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/149558/recommended-vim-plugins-for-c-coding/152448#152448) which was initially restricted to C development. However every thing I said is still valid for C++.

Comment: `sudo apt install eclipse` :-)

Answer (score 171, accepted):

- Code complete: [Omni completion](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/VimTip1608) or [Clang autocomplete](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3302) or [YouCompleteMe](https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe)
- Real time syntax checking: [Syntastic](https://github.com/scrooloose/syntastic)
- Switching between source and header file: [A plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=31)
- Snippets: [Snipmate](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2540) or [UltiSnip](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2715)
- Search for reference of variables, functions, classes, etc.: [Cscope](http://cscope.sourceforge.net/cscope_vim_tutorial.html)
- Go to definition: [Ctags](http://ctags.sourceforge.net/) or part of [YouCompleteMe subcommands](https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe#the-gotodefinitionelsedeclaration-subcommand) mentioned above
- Refactoring tools: [Refactor](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2087), [lh-refactor](https://github.com/LucHermitte/vim-refactor)
- Useful text objects: [Arg text object](http://www.vim.org/scripts//script.php?script_id=2699) and [Class text object](http://www.reddit.com/r/vim/comments/e99h9/is_there_a_way_to_change_the_way_and_move/c16duif)
- [C++ category in Vim Tips wiki](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Category:C%2B%2B)
- [Luc Hermitte's C/C++ plugin](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-cpp)
- Not C++ specific but I also recommend either [FuzzyFinder](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1984) or [Command-T](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3025) or [Unite](https://github.com/Shougo/unite.vim) for file navigation. With either of these, you don't even need tabs (which does not scale for 10+ files) to manage your project.
- Class navigation:  [Taglist](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=273) or [Tagbar](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3465)

Edit: Updated as of July 2013

Comment: I've fixed the link to my C&C++ ftplugins suite. Thanks for the "advertizing" :)

Comment: Also I may recomend FSwitch plugin instead of A plugin.

Comment: Luc's lhCpp is incompatible with vundle (I think due to svn repo) and no install process I like personally - recommend checking out https://github.com/Raimondi/delimitMate

Comment: Because of all dependencies in my plugins suite, I highly recommend to install it with VimAddonManager (type `:InstallAddon lh-cpp`, or `call vam#ActivateAddons(['lh-cpp'])` in your .vimrc, and you should be done with it) . This way I can keep my (viml) code base DRY and focus on advanced features.

Comment: +1 a very complete (and up to date) answer deserves it, it's nice to see some of the more reclusive members posting these great answers. How thorough your answer is, is quite helpful, while at the same time not overwhelming, even to a new vim user.

Comment: How about vim-rtags? It's good for c++ code navigation, has a rename functionality.

Comment: I know this is an old thread, however useful for people stumbling here; here is a vimrc which I use for C/C++ and python development with autocompletion of code https://github.com/tbhaskar78/vimrc/blob/master/vimrc

Comment: It is a long list of different purposes. Would you share which one your favorite and which one do you use...the most?

Answer (score 10):

I'm using `vim` as my C++ editor, however I'm not using many 'exotic' stuff.

- Regarding completion, I'm using the non-contextual `^P` and `^N`.
- I have a bunch of user defined abbreviations for my C++ use, for example :

  ```
  abbreviate bptr boost::shared_ptr
  abbreviate cstr const std::string &
  ```
- I have several functions for "code snippets" like things, for example :

  ```
  function! IncludeGuard()
    let basename = expand("%:t:r")
    let includeGuard = '__' . basename . '_h__'
    call append(0, "#ifndef " . includeGuard)
    call append(1, "#define " . includeGuard)
    call append(line("$"), "#endif /* !" . includeGuard . " */")
  endfunction
  ```
- The only plugin I really couldn't live without is [Command-T](https://wincent.com/products/command-t) (which requires ruby support)
- For easy `.cc` to `.h` switching, you can try [this plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=31)

Comment: it's recommended to use [`std::string_view`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view) instead of `const std::string &` when working with C++17 or higher

Answer (score 4):

NERDTree http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1658

Exuberant ctags (vim already supports the hotkeys natively) http://ctags.sourceforge.net/

taglist: http://vim-taglist.sourceforge.net/

snipmate: http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2540

I don't do omnicompletion just the usual ^n ^p stuff but there are plenty of resources to google for.