# Setting up vim as C++ IDE

Tags: c++, vim, ide

I wish to setup vim as C++ IDE so I can do all work from it.

I'm using these plugins for vim:

-   Clang complete - accurate completion
-   nerdtree - browse files
-   snipmate - insert snippets
-   AutoComplPop - omni-completion
-   buffergator - buffer management
-   vim-powerline - nice statusbar
-   vundle - to manage plugins

But I lack things like Jump to definition and compiling multiple files in one executable, project view...

I'm using

```
nmap <F8> :w % <bar> :!g++ -W -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -std=c++11 % -o %:t:r<CR> <bar> :!./%:t:r<CR>
```

to compile current file, but it won't work if there are multiple file that create one executable.

I know I could just use eclipse, netbeans, code::blocks and such, but I really like vim... If such thing as vim ide isn't possible do I have to learn GNU build system or some other method?

Any advice is welcome.

Comment: If you write a quick makefile (Or have one generated) you can just run !make

Comment: @jozefg, `!make` will just run external make and that's it. there is built-in `make` command in vim which will also create a `quickfix` window with errors/warnings. It's much more useful

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to create a makefile which handles the build process.

Then from vim just run `:make`, it will run the build and pop all errors in `quickfix` window where you can navigate and jump to error locations.

Comment: Any way to automate the creation of makefile?

Comment: I know this thread is old but you can use cmake. It's relatively easy to use and your code can be compiled in different platforms.

Comment: Even more old now, but I have been using premake for this for years. I bind a vim key to a command that lets premake generate the make file, then run make and then run the built executable.

Answer (score 2):

First, to jump to definitions, you might try this:

- http://www.santiagolizardo.com/article/vim-jump-to-classes-and-functions-defined-in-different-files/64003

I haven't tested it, so I can't tell you if it works.

Now, to build multiple file projects, it might be better for you to learn how to use makefiles and automake. These links might help you:

- http://homepages.gac.edu/~mc38/2001J/documentation/g++.html
- http://www.openismus.com/documents/linux/automake/automake

Good luck.

Edit: A similar question was answered on this link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/563992/1820837

Answer (score 2):

"Jump to definition" is already there, it's `<C-]>` with the cursor on a keyword or `:tag foo` on the command line.

For these to work, you need a `tags` file generated by exuberant-ctags and to tell Vim where to find it. See `:help tags` and `:help ctags`.

Without a `tags` file, `gd` goes to the definition of the keyword under your cursor if it's in the same file. But it's not as generally useful as `<C-]>`.

Comment: Everything is correct, but, as usually, I would add the same suggestion: I recommend not to deal with ctags manually, but use plugin Indexer instead ( http://goo.gl/Q744m ), it does all the painful work automatically: it silently generates your tags, tells Vim where to look for it, and keeps tags up-to-date. All the work is done in background, so, you don't need to wait for it.

Answer (score 1):

For "Jump to definition" I can recommend the [YouCompleteMe](https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe), plugin which is really easy to setup with [vundle](https://github.com/gmarik/Vundle.vim).

Otherwise there is also [ctags](https://github.com/vim-scripts/ctags.vim), but I find it less useful.

To use vim as a IDE, I find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4237817/help-with-configuring-vim-for-c) post useful.