# define default text for vim editor

Tags: vim

I want vim to have the option that whenever I make a new c++ file with vim , it writes my base code text in it automatically . such as :

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;
int main(){
}
```

please help!
sorry because of my bad English

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Configuring Vim for C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4237817/configuring-vim-for-c)

Comment: Especially look for "snippets": https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%2B%2B%5D+%5Bvim%5D+snippet

Comment: thank you @phd but I don't know exactly what to do .. i think i have to make some changes in vimrc file , but i don't know how

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Noah Frederick wrote [an excellent article](https://noahfrederick.com/log/vim-templates-with-ultisnips-and-projectionist) on how to use ultisnips to create "skeleton" files:

Basically, his script detects when a file is created and triggers a pre defined snippet. Of course you have also to install [ultisnips](https://github.com/sirver/UltiSnips).

Someone could ask: Why do not create a file template and trigger it via autocommands? The answer is simple, the ultisnips solution allows you to change your template on demand, it is no just a static template and [you can see](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QsLTYEVJ6JU) Noah explaining the ideas behind his solution.

```
"             File: ultisnips_custom.vim - Custom UltiSnips settings
"       Maintainer: Sergio Araújo
" Oririnal Creator: Noah Frederick
"        Reference: https://noahfrederick.com/log/vim-templates-with-ultisnips-and-projectionist
"      Last Change: out 11, 2020 - 17:18
"      Place it at: after/plugin/ultisnips_custom.vim

" We need python or python3 to run ultisnips
if !has("python") && !has("python3")
  finish
endif

" This function is called by the autocommand at the end of the file
function! TestAndLoadSkel() abort
  let filename = expand('%')
  " Abort on non-empty buffer or extant file
  if !(line('$') == 1 && getline('$') == '') || filereadable('%')
    return
  endif

  " Load UltiSnips in case it was deferred via vim-plug
  if !exists('g:did_plugin_ultisnips') && exists(':PlugStatus')
    call plug#load('ultisnips')
    doautocmd FileType
  endif

  " the function feedkys simulates the insert key sequence in order to call
  " the template (skel)
  execute 'call feedkeys("i_skel\<C-r>=UltiSnips#ExpandSnippet()\<CR>")'
endfunction
" remember to create a _skel snippet with your header for each file you
" want a autosnippet 

augroup ultisnips_custom
  autocmd!
  au Bufnewfile *.sh,*.zsh,*.html,*.css,*.py,*.tex,*.txt,*.md,*.vim :call TestAndLoadSkel()
augroup END

" vim: fdm=marker:sw=2:sts=2:et
```

Answer (score 1):

Just save that file as a vim template to `$HOME/.vim/templates/cc.tpl`. Whenver you edit a new file named `foo.cc` -- voilà!