# Debugging C++ in (Neo)vim

Tags: c++, c++11, vim, c++17, neovim

I just switched from windows 10 to arch linux
I want to use (Neo)Vim as my code editor
I've sitted up autocomplition
and Fuzzy finder
But I have no idea how to debug in (Neo)Vim

Any helps!

Comment: What are your expectations? Vim in tandem with Make can help you to jump to the locations of compiler errors from the build process, but that is not "debugging" IMHO. If you want step-debugging on the command line, that is usually done in GDB, not in Vim. Please be more specific about your needs.

Answer (score 8):

For neovim there is [nvim-dap](https://github.com/mfussenegger/nvim-dap) which is an implementation of the debugging interface called [DAP](https://microsoft.github.io/debug-adapter-protocol/) which vscode uses as well. For c/c++ check this [page](https://github.com/mfussenegger/nvim-dap/wiki/C-C---Rust-(gdb-via--vscode-cpptools)) in nvim-dap's wiki.

Answer (score 1):

Until this moment I have just used Neovim/Vim to change some small things in a code on terminal, but I think that installing the [Kite](https://www.kite.com/) plugin can help a little bit while you are coding and also, I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3536600/do-you-debug-c-code-in-vim-how), that has some considerations and possibilities  of debuggers for Vim.

Answer (score 1):

If you use gdb, you can use the in-built debugger plugin `TermDebug`. This works with both Vim and Neovim and is quite nice for C and C++ debugging.